# "concave-down function" times "concave-down function" is also concave-down?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

The title is somewhat vague. Specifically, let both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are **concave-down** , **decreasing**, and **positive** on the interval $[0, A]$.

For example, $f(x)=-x^2+1$ and $g(x)=\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}$. Then both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are concave-down and decreasing when $0\leq x \leq A=1$.

[image]

**My question : Let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$. Then naturally $h(s)$ is decreasing on $[0, A]$.
              But I am not sure if $h(s)$ is also concave-down....**

Comment: consider $(-x^2) (-x^2)$

Comment: What if you subtract 1 from both of your functions?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added the constraint that both functions are positive on the interval.

Comment: Why don't you work a general argument with functions $f,g$, and their respective derivatives, which tell you about concavity?

Answer (score 2):

This answer addressed an earlier version of the question in which $f$ and $g$ did not need to be positive functions.

---

Choose $f(x) = g(x) = -x^2$. These are decreasing on $(0, \infty)$ and concave down, but $fg(x) = x^4$ is not.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive on $[0, A]$ like the examples I took. Thanks for your answer, anyway. Considering the constraint, is $h(x)$ is concave-down?

Answer (score 1):

Functions could be positive decreasing and concave down but still the result won't be concave down. Consider $f=g=(1-x^2)$ and $fg$ on $[-1,1]$. Here is the [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%281-x%5E2%29%5E2). The second derivative, $12x^2-4$, shows an inflection point inside the interval.